# how to generate a list of currently active proxies in python

Tags: python, proxy

I have a python script where I get connected to some sites through proxy if direct connection fails. What I want to do is get a list of currently active proxies and I cant figure out how to do so

I am generating proxy through this:

```
 proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8080'})
 opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
 urllib2.install_opener(opener)
 urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
```

Please help